# Linked sub tables in Entity Framework code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Quite a simple scenario but there are so many permutations of EF examples around it's hard to find the exact one you need. I have a User table which contains the primary user information but then I want sub tables for related information such as one for the users profile, one for the users search criteria, one for their location. For example I have the following tables

User
UserProfile
UserSearchCriteria

I want the user object to contain the other objects and retrieve them when you retrieve the User object, so from the code I could say User.Profile.MainText or User.Location.Postcode for example. The User table should generate the primary UserId key and that should be the key used for UserProfile, UserSearch.

So after inserting my user object which contains nested userprofile and usersearch objects, I should have an entry in User table with a new identity insert UserId, and also a row each in the other two tables, with the same primary key inserted as the UserId.

With my code so far, it does this but the only undesirable thing is I get additional columns on the User table, repeating the UserId for each foreign key association. I will paste my class code for the User class and one of the nested classes so you get the idea

```
[Table("User")]
    public class DbUser
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(80)]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(80)]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(80)]
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(1)]
        public string Gender { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public virtual DbGeographicalArea Location { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(80)]
        public string Profession { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public DateTime DateJoined { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public DateTime LastLoggedOn { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(1)]
        public string Status { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(500)]
        public string StatusNotes { get; set; }

        public virtual DbUserMatchCriteria UserMatchCriteria { get; set; }

        public virtual DbUserMatchLifestyle UserMatchLifestyle { get; set; }

        public virtual DbUserProfile Profile { get; set; }

        public virtual DbUserPassword Password { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<DbUserPhoto> Photos { get; set; }
    }

[Table("UserMatchCriteria")]
    public class DbUserMatchCriteria
    {
        [Key]
        public int UserId { get; set; }


    }
}
```

The User table has all the required columns generated when I save the object using EF code first and the UserMatchCriteria table creates fine, but the only problem is at the end of the User table columns, I have an extra unwanted column called UserMatchCriteria_UserId which just contains the same ID as the main UserId, so it's like there is a two way association between these two tables when I only want a one way association.

Is my approach or thinking wrong? I suppose if the DB models the code exactly then you SHOULD have this column as in the code, the User object knows about the UserMatchCriteria object, but with my history of relational databases, this feels wrong to me in SQL to have those unnecessary repeated columns at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the native behavior of Code-First with 1-1 entity relationships. The use of an ORM is meant to abstract these sorts of implementation details.

Additionally, you may want to consider removing the `Key` annotation from `DbUserMatchCriteria` which would make it a [Complex Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj679962) and inlined.

UPDATE: The trade off is that you could end up with fairly wide rows. This could cause additional paging. But two tables require a join or potentially another trip to the database. But these differences may be trivial relative to things like network latency.

So like all performance concerns, it's dependent on lots of factors and the only way to really know is to measure.

Comment: If I remove the [Key] attribute on DbUserMatchCriteria it throws a model validation error saying a key is not defined?

Comment: Sorry yeah. You'd also have to remove the `TableAttribute` and then regenerate schema. You might like this schema less but it's an option :) And if you're interacting with entites from code then it would be seamless.

Comment: One more thing. If you align to the naming conventions in the linked document, annotations aren't required. Resulting in completely clean POCOs. I really enjoy coding this way.

Comment: Hmm yes I see, interesting. Now I have a conundrum, to make them all one big complex type table or to split out into different tables..... I guess there really isn't a big difference as they are all 1-1 so there's no reason not to keep them all in one table I suppose..... certainly keeps it cleaner for deleting cascades or updating etc...... Are there any major pros/cons I'm not thinking of? But in this instance it certainly seems to me like both are identically attractive.

Comment: Yeah I saw that, nice. But surely you still need the Required and MaxLength ones?

Comment: Updated answer with pros/cons. Good point on `MaxLength`. `Required` is indicated by whether the column's type is `Nullable` i.e. int? vs int